# how to pass tableview from one view controller hide to another view controller unhide using button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to IOS i created two view controller.First view controller contain tableview as table1 and Second view controller contains button. I want to pass table1 to second view controller and unhide table1 in button action.

pop up for second view controller 
[image: sample of second viewcontroller]

first view controller after button action in second view controller

[image: i want this type date can be added in first controller using tableviewcell]

Comment: have you attempted this on your own yet? do you have any code you can provide?

Comment: are u using storyboard or

Comment: yes storyboard only @JoyalClifford

Comment: U cant pass enter table in second VC. u can pass table Data in Second VC.

Comment: yes on my own and which part code are you expecting either tableview or button action in second view controller @user3353890

Comment: U can do one think, create one more table in second VC and hide it. when Button get action ,made visble it

Comment: But i need tableview in first controller hidden and second view controller in button action it can be appear first controller tableview whether its possible to do @JoyalClifford

Comment: yes you can create new table dynamically on buttton action and pass data on secondviewcontroller and disply on it.

Comment: you can also use notification center for the same

Comment: yes it possible. when button get action just push into firstVC

Comment: can have any sample coding for push into firstVC@JoyalClifford

Comment: @JoyalClifford yes you can also poptoviewcontroller for manage stack of view controller

Comment: Do you want a Slide-out Sidebar Menu in Your App..??

Comment: check my update i need this type controller using tableview  @luckyShubhra

Answer (score 0):

For instance, consider I had two view controllers. The first contains one button and the second needs to know information on the first view . You could wire the buttons up to an IBAction in your code which uses performSegueWithIdentifier: method, like this...

```
// When any of my buttons are pressed, push the next view
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
}

// This will get called too before the view appears
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

For more information you can see this: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/